# Are questions about calculating the Metonic Calendar on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

This question - [How many days are there in each year of the 304th Metonic cycle?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114681/how-many-days-are-there-in-each-year-of-the-304th-metonic-cycle) - and similar *Metonic* ones are being asked by the same user.

Can one simply point him to the relevant literature (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) and mark it as off-topic?

There's nothing "Jewish" about helping this user with historical calendar information. (Except for "doing them a favor, maybe.)

Add to that the fact that the Wikipedia page on Metonic Calendar says that the Luach is a specific subset, so it's probably inaccurate to refer to the Luach as the Metonic calendar.

So, should we continue to charm this user, or decide this is off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

> the Wikipedia page on Metonic Calendar says that the Luach is a specific subset

Well, if the question is actually about the Jewish calendar, and the question is calling it the metonic calendar, then the question is on-topic as far as I can tell (afaIct) (and should be edited for clarity).

If the question is actually about some other metonic calendar, then it's off-topic afaIct.

If it's about metonic calendars in general, then afaIct it's like any other general-knowledge question, which [can be on-topic](/a/1474/170).

Just my opinion.